# How I can do this "light streaks" or "linear lights" in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, lighting-effects

Can someone teach me how to do this lights?
I don't even know how to call them.
Not the black silhouette, the lights (the "***lines***" and that "***light up***"),
Thanks!

[image: cover]

Comment: do you have an image you're starting with, or are you trying to build a graphic from scratch? (for the latter, it would be easier in Illustrator)

Comment: @AshleePalka Yes, I'm building a graphic from scratch but only to have a better way to doing things like this. Is It easier in Ilustrator? Then teach how can I do it please.

Comment: It would be helpful to see what you tried. What specifically are you struggling with? This isn't a tutorial site, but we'll help you with specific issues. Please edit your question to include your progress and the specific problems you are having. :)

Comment: @AshleePalka Well, I do some lines. I try to put same colors as the cover. But the part that I'm trying to do is that light. I don't know how to do it. It's like a shooting star effect (not the meme) that I'm trying to do.  How I can add lights effects like that in Photoshop or Ilustrator. (I try it in both programs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some coarse Illustrator tricks to get some of the wanted gradient effects. Blurs are kept quite minimal. The contrast and color saturation are high. In your model image the colors are flattened to printable range, the highest contrast is reserved for the silhouette and there are much larger blurs than in my example.

See the following cartoon:

[image]

1. Draw a dark backround to see the white. Draw a rectangle and make a bunch of copies. I have this many different colors (W, R, G, B, Y and M) only for easy communication.
2. Shorten R and G, rotate B, Y and M to the same tilted angle, it's about -80 degrees. Move B to the top of W
3. Add linear gradients. G, B and Y get white to magenta. NOTE: I call them still G, B and Y.
4. Give to Y the Gaussian Blur effect. Duplicate Y to the same place to thicken the opacity of the blur. Give to M the Outer Glow effect (Effect > Stylize > Outer Glow, color = Magenta)
5. Move Y and M to the same place as B. On the top is Y, in the middle is B and below them is M. Give to Red elliptical gradient from white to black. It's a radial gradient, but adjusted horizontally much narrower, actually as wide as our rectangles. This really needs some practicing.
6. Move R onto G, select both, goto the panel options (top right corner) of the Transparency panel and select Make Opacity Mask. Move the resulted tail to the top of W.

To keep the selections easy lock the background in the beginning. You can return to adjust the effects via the appearance panel. The gradients are adjustable in the Gradients panel. All those panels are under the Window menu.

Comment: WOW! Well thats even better, I'm gonna try it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make paths with the pen tool, stroke them with a fine brush and play with your blending options such as Outer glow and Drop shadow.

Comment: to collect a good bunch of upvotes you should add a screenshot - one image that has for example three versions of a pair of differently colored lightbars+glows +  tails in different construction phases. And, of course, an explanation of the different phases is a must.

Comment: Nods. You are absolutely right, i was a little bit in a rush and not sure if I'd be able to exactly replicate the effect the OP wanted to see. But thanks for the tip anyways, i'll mind it next time.

Comment: @SWEETSCouture  Thanks! It's what I wanted to do.